# Toggle audio in JS

Tags: javascript, audio, toggle

I have code that when and image is clicked by the user, it plays an  audio file.

```
    <script>
  function playSong(){
       var audio = document.getElementById("suess");
       audio.play();
                 }
   </script>
<input type="image" src="suessical.jpg" onclick="playSong()" alt="Click to play a song from the show!">
<audio id="suess" src="http://ninjareviews.hostreo.com/Seussical-the-Musical-Green-Eggs-and-Ham.mp3"></audio>\
```

How would I modify the script so that when the same image is clicked again, the music pauses and resumes when clicked again? Would I have to use JQuery or can I use JS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Used a toggle based on the `paused` property:

```
function playSong(){
   var audio = document.getElementById("suess");
   if (audio.paused) audio.play();
   else audio.pause();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You access on audio object the information if it is paused or not.

`if (audio.paused) { audio.play(); } else { audio.pause(); }`.

More info: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_av_dom.asp